# very low val_accuracy vs accuracy - text classification (multi class)

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I've been working for a while now on a bug classification project.

My goal is to: **"given a new bug, I'd like to predict which 'final owner group' it will be assigned to (6 labels as targets)"**

I've several features which I was able to extract from a database (around 17000 samples):

1. subject ===>> free text
2. description ===>> free text
3. has_errors ===>> boolean ('yes' or 'no')
4. has_panics ===>> boolean ('yes' or 'no')
5. has_images ===>> boolean ('yes' or 'no')
6. committer groups ===>> a categorical field
7. reporter group ===>> a categorical field

and finally the target labels which (as mentioned) has 6 possible outputs (categorical as well)

After pre-processing (tokenizing + stemming) I've decided to use `keras` functional API and consolidate all the above features into 2 main groups:

1. free text features
2. categorical features

Thus ending up with 2 layers as inputs to the model.
Below is my code for how the model was made:

```
vocab_size = 1000
embedding_dim = 16
max_length = 128
trunc_type='post'
padding_type='post'
oov_tok = "<OOV>"


# prepare input data
def prepare_inputs(X_train, X_test):
    oe = OrdinalEncoder()
    oe.fit(X_train)
    X_train_enc = oe.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test_enc = oe.fit_transform(X_test)
    return X_train_enc, X_test_enc
 
# prepare free text input
def prepare_free_text_inputs(X_train, X_test):
    training_sentences = X_train['message'] + ' ' + X_train['description']
    testing_sentences = X_test['message'] + ' ' + X_test['description']
    tokenizer = Tok(num_words=vocab_size, oov_token=oov_tok)
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(training_sentences)
    word_index = tokenizer.word_index
    
    training_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(training_sentences)
    training_padded = pad_sequences(training_sequences, maxlen=max_length, padding=padding_type, truncating=trunc_type)
    
    testing_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(testing_sentences)
    testing_padded = pad_sequences(testing_sequences, maxlen=max_length, padding=padding_type, truncating=trunc_type)
    return training_padded, testing_padded
    
    
# prepare target
def prepare_targets(y_train, y_test):
    le = LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(y_train)
    y_train_enc = le.transform(y_train)
    y_test_enc = le.transform(y_test)
    return y_train_enc, y_test_enc
 

# prepare free_text input data
X_train_tokenized, X_test_tokenized = prepare_free_text_inputs(X_train, X_test)

# prepare categorical input data
X_train_ord, X_test_ord = prepare_inputs(X_train.iloc[:, 2:], X_test.iloc[:, 2:])


# prepare output data
y_train_enc, y_test_enc = prepare_targets(y_train, y_test)


input_free_text = Input(shape=(128,))
x = Embedding(vocab_size, 64)(input_free_text)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(x)
model_free_text = Model(inputs=input_free_text, outputs=x)

input_categorical = Input(shape=(5,))
x = Embedding(100, 1)(input_categorical)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(1, activation="relu")(x)
model_categorical = Model(inputs=input_categorical, outputs=x)

combined = Concatenate()([model_free_text.output, model_categorical.output])

z = Dense(6, activation='softmax')(combined)
model = Model(inputs=[model_free_text.input, model_categorical.input], outputs=z)


model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

model.summary()
keras.utils.plot_model(model, "model.png", show_shapes=True)
history = model.fit(x=[X_train_tokenized, X_train_ord], y=y_train_enc, 
                    validation_data=([X_test_tokenized, X_test_ord], y_test_enc), 
                    batch_size=64, epochs=10)

test_scores = model.evaluate(x=[X_test_tokenized, X_test_ord], y=y_test_enc, verbose=0)
print("Test loss:", test_scores[0])
print("Test accuracy:", test_scores[1])
```

Sadly I'm getting very bad results which (from my understanding) clearly indicates my model is overfitting:

```
Total params: 592,914
Trainable params: 592,914
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/10
183/183 [==============================] - 2s 7ms/step - loss: 1.7274 - accuracy: 0.2966 - val_loss: 1.5990 - val_accuracy: 0.3385
Epoch 2/10
183/183 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 1.4058 - accuracy: 0.4388 - val_loss: 1.3112 - val_accuracy: 0.4875
Epoch 3/10
183/183 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 1.1609 - accuracy: 0.5490 - val_loss: 1.2607 - val_accuracy: 0.5177
Epoch 4/10
183/183 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.9554 - accuracy: 0.6378 - val_loss: 1.3092 - val_accuracy: 0.5290
Epoch 5/10
183/183 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7538 - accuracy: 0.7200 - val_loss: 1.4642 - val_accuracy: 0.5390
Epoch 6/10
183/183 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.5989 - accuracy: 0.7815 - val_loss: 1.6008 - val_accuracy: 0.5294
Epoch 7/10
183/183 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.4782 - accuracy: 0.8321 - val_loss: 1.8287 - val_accuracy: 0.5170
Epoch 8/10
183/183 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.3978 - accuracy: 0.8639 - val_loss: 2.0652 - val_accuracy: 0.5256
Epoch 9/10
183/183 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.3329 - accuracy: 0.8879 - val_loss: 2.1645 - val_accuracy: 0.5218
Epoch 10/10
183/183 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.2734 - accuracy: 0.9063 - val_loss: 2.3494 - val_accuracy: 0.5256
Test loss: 2.3494064807891846
Test accuracy: 0.5255749821662903
```

Although I've vast experience with Python I'm a newbie to ML field.
I'm mentioning that since I've to admit I didn't really understand what input all layer should get (e.g. `Dense` layers) and I was relaying on different examples I've found.

It's important to mention that I've already given it a shot with `sklearn` pipeline and ended up with ~70% accuracy.

Also - my data is imbalanced.

What am I doing wrong here?
Are those my inputs needs adjustment? Something else?

**UPDATE:**

it turns out I've used the `OrdinalEncoder` wrong (per the advice in the comments) - after handling that. I got the model overfits much later.

Here are the last epoch statistics:

```
Epoch 20/20
92/92 [==============================] - 1s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0487 - accuracy: 0.6483 - val_loss: 1.5710 - val_accuracy: 0.5774
Test loss: 1.5709956884384155
Test accuracy: 0.5774115920066833
```

So that looks much more reasonable - but the scores are still bad.

Any idea for improvements will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could possibly be because you're doing fit_transform on both sets in your input encoding function, which is unnecessary as you've already called `oe.fit(train)` so just do `X_train_enc = oe.transform(X_train)` for both, which then won't overwrite your `oe`

Comment: @ML_Engine Thanks :) I've changed that and now indeed `accuracy` and `val_accuracy` are both very similar - no overfitting.
The problem is they're both very low I got 57% test accuracy (vs 58% accuracy)
I'll update the question with the new findings.

Comment: I would perhaps try increasing the number of neurons, and maybe add some dense layers to your categorical sub model

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have enough data to be using a NN for this kind of problem and the problem you have is not suitable for it either.

Naive Bayes models could be useful here with some preprocessing and feature generation.
Tree models could also be useful. Look into CountVectorizer for preprocessing.

Regarding the imbalance you could downsample or upsample your data, a little bit of imbalance is not a problem, but a large imbalance is and needs to be taken care of.
There is also the possiblity of using for example class weights in tree models or model specific methods to handle imbalance. I've found that NNs can be quite sensitive to data imbalance.

Comment: I've actually managed to get 84% val_accuracy and 85% accuracy by tweaking the params and using data augmentation. Also added class weights helped. Do you still think I should neglect the NN approach?